# Format a list with multiple lines in Jade?

Tags: pug

Does anyone know how I can format a list with multiple lines in Jade?

What i need is:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="assets/img/image1.jpg">
    Mister X<br />
    Phone: 1234567890
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="assets/img/image2.jpg">
    Mister Y<br />
    Phone: 1234567890
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
ul
  li
    img(src='assets/img/image1.jpg')
    Mister X<br />Phone: 1234567890
  li
    img(src='assets/img/image1.jpg')
    Mister Y<br />Phone: 1234567890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it like this:

```
 ul
      li
        img(src='assets/img/image1.jpg')
        |     Mister X
        br
        |     Phone: 1234567890
      li
        img(src='assets/img/image2.jpg')
        |     Mister Y
        br
        |     Phone: 1234567890
```

You can make experiments with online tools such as HTML2Jade or Jade2HTML convertors:
http://html2jade.org/

http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Answer (score 0):

ul
            li
                img(src='assets/img/image1.jpg')
                Mister X
                br
                Phone: 1234567890
            li
                img(src='assets/img/image2.jpg')
                Mister Y
                br
                Phone: 1234567890